# Create a ReportingServices data source and upload to a data connection library

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, reporting-services

I have installed reporting services 2012 in **SharePoint 2013 integrated mode**. I need to create a report data source and upload it to a data connection library **using C#**.

As I know it uses the ReportingServices2010 class but **I cannot explore a reporting server url**.

There is a ReportingServices2010.asmx file in the 15 hive though.

Also it works fine when I manually set the data source.

Answer (score 0):

you can go to Reporting Service Configuration Manager and click of Web Service Url.

Add "ReportService2010.asmx" at end.